# How to turn functions into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a basic JavaScript quiz and I heard that making it into jquery makes it easier to work with things. How can I change these functions such as next and images into jquery? I took out a few of the questions for length's sake. I am very new to learning jquerys so any help is appreciated.

```
var pos = 0,
  test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct = 0;

var questions = [{ //1
  question: "What is Dazai's power from Bungo Stray Dogs?",
  img: "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/14/313453.jpg",
  a: "No Longer Human",
  b: "For the Tainted Sorrow",
  c: "Rashomon",
  d: "Unbreakable",
  answer: "A"
  //Add property to hold image source uri, either local or online

}, ];

function get(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

function renderQuestion() {
  test = get("test");
  if (pos >= questions.length) {
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
    get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed";

    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;

    return false;
  }
  get("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;

  question = questions[pos].question;
  chA = questions[pos].a;
  chB = questions[pos].b;
  chC = questions[pos].c;
  chD = questions[pos].d;

  img = questions[pos].img;

  test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";

  test.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + img + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"><be>";


  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " + chD + "</label><br><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}

function checkAnswer() {

  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }

  if (choice == questions[pos].answer) {

    correct++;
  }

  pos++;

  renderQuestion();
}

window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion);
```

Comment: At first glance I don't see any event handlers in there. I just see functions. Whether you should use jQuery is a hotly debated topic. Many say it's an obsolete library for most cases.

Comment: @isherwood Ok, I did not know,  question is it possible to change my functions into jquerys?

Comment: @DominicJohnson, jQuery is just extra syntax you can use-- often simpler-- to do what you're doing in "vanilla" javascript. If your vanilla JS is working fine, feel free to use it. If you like the extra features and functionality of using jQuery, you can introduce it piecemeal. But your question doesn't really have an _answer_ the way it's written.

Comment: I would search for things like jquery equivalent document.getElementById and innerhtml

Comment: @FSDford ok thank you.

Comment: People have been saying things like jQuery and Coldfusion are dead for years.  I try to ignore those people.

Comment: Don't use jQuery _just_ for this but if you have other reasons for using it, go for it. My preference is to keep javascript and HTML separate (working with HTML nativly you are more likely to pick up mistakes like `<be>` tags). Perhaps look at using the `<template>` tag to template your question which you then populate and add to the DOM with javascript/jQuery

Comment: Also one important point to remember jQuery **IS** javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I think most people use JQuery when they are dealing with the dom and events.  There are other uses, but these are the 2 most common in my opinion.

getElementById

```
// JavaScript - getElement
var e = document.getElementById('myDiv');

// JavaScript - querySelector
var e = document.querySelector('#myDiv')

// Jquery
var e = $('#myDiv')
```

Adding Classes

```
// JavaScript
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach((e)=>{
    e.classList.add('red');
});

// Jquery
$('.button').addClass('red');
```

Overall it shortens up your code. You can do everything in vanilla JavaScript and often times it's faster to do it in vanilla Js.

Jquery was super useful back when there was a lot of browser compatibility issues. It can still be useful today, but the file size is a bit hefty. You may want to look for alternatives. There are some amazing ones that have 1 for 1 syntax, but missing some of the backward compatibility making them 10% of the size.

It has been a while, you might want to check jquery's website. They used to have different builds, so maybe they have a smaller version. Otherwise, I would suggest checking out some youtube tutorials.

A direct translation would be something like this:

```
var pos = 0,
  test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct = 0;

var questions = [{ //1
  question: "What is Dazai's power from Bungo Stray Dogs?",
  img: "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/14/313453.jpg",
  a: "No Longer Human",
  b: "For the Tainted Sorrow",
  c: "Rashomon",
  d: "Unbreakable",
  answer: "A"
  //Add property to hold image source uri, either local or online

}, ];

function renderQuestion() {
    var test = $("#test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.html("<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>");
        $("#test_status").html("Test completed");
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    $('#test_status').html("Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length);
    question = questions[pos].question;
    chA = questions[pos].a;
    chB = questions[pos].b;
    chC = questions[pos].c;
    chD = questions[pos].d;

    img = questions[pos].img;

    test.html("<h3>" + question + "</h3>");
    test.append("<img src=\"" + img + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"><be>");
    test.append("<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "</label><be>");
    test.append("<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "</label><be>");
    test.append("<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "</label><be>");
    test.append("<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " + chD + "</label><br><be>");
    test.append("<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>");
}

function checkAnswer() {
    var choice;
    $('[name="choices"').forEach((e)=>{
        if(e.checked){
            choice = e.value;
        }
    });
    if(choice == questions[pos].answer){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}

window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a basic JavaScript quiz

You're starting point is plain "Vanilla" JavaScript, not jQuery. Since you're starting with JS, keep it at that, until you have a compelling requirement to refactor your logic into jQuery syntax. Also, choosing to support jQuery comes with a little bit of overhead, as you'll need to include the library into your page.

> I heard that making it into jquery makes it easier to work with things

You've already written your logic in JS. While it's true jQuery has some helper functions, I wouldn't suggest refactoring your code because frankly, it doesn't appear you have sufficient grasp of either Vanilla JS or jQuery to make the evaluation. (Not trying to be rude at all, just an observation.)

Since jQuery is a JS library, if you learn Vanilla JS first then you'll be able to determine if jQuery is helpful for a particular task. If you learn jQuery before JS, you'll won't be able to tell. So my hotly debated answer is: Start with JS and gain proficiency with it, then begin evaluating other JS libraries and frameworks.